# tmux how to bind a key to enter in VI mode and search backwards?

Tags: tmux

I think that my routine, in Tmux,  of ctrl+b [ and then ? to enter in VI mode and then start to search backwards is a little cumbersome and I wonder if it's possible to map a key combination, like ctrl-/ to do that.

Any idea of how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get a straight `<C-/>`, mapping as you'll still have to enter the prefix. e.g. `<C-b><C-/>`  . Then you might ask the question, is that any better than `<C-b>[?`  ?

Comment: I was able to map shift + down to create new windows with the command
`bind -n S-down new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}`. So it may be possible.
Even if it's not possible to remove the prefix it will be an improvement for sure, since I do this tens of times everyday.

Comment: If you simply want the shortest mapping `<C-b>/`  is the shortest I can see, and it doesn't seem to have a default tmux mapping

Comment: It's better, for sure. Thanks. Any idea of which command I use in the mapping?

Comment: ok, I got something pretty close, will post an answer now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running these two commands will give this mapping: <kbd>prefix</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>,<kbd>/</kbd> (you'll need to hit `/` twice.) which will put you into copy mode and then `search-backwards`

```
bind-key / copy-mode
bind-key -t vi-copy '/' search-backward
```

Mapping <kbd>/</kbd> to search-backward causes you to (obviously) lose forward search which you might want because tmux sometimes puts the cursor at the top of the text in copy mode (e.g. when you run `list-keys`, . But you might be able to re-work the commands from this basic idea.

#### Background

If you look in *WINDOWS AND CLIENTS* section in man page: `man tmux | less '+/^WINDOWS'`

> Mode key bindings are defined in a set of named tables: vi-edit and
>   emacs-edit for keys used when line editing at the command prompt;
>   vi-choice and emacs-choice for keys used when choosing from lists (such
>        as produced by the choose-window command); and vi-copy and emacs-copy
>        used in copy mode.  The tables may be viewed with the list-keys command
>        and keys modified or removed with bind-key and unbind-key.

This tells you you can list the `vi-copy` keys with

```
list-keys -t vi-copy
```

from there you can look up which commands you want to remap.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but I believe that it's what is possible

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```
bind-key Space run "tmux copy-mode; tmux send-keys ?"
```

with this, you can just press prefix+space to enter copy-mode + backwardsearch

Answer (score 0):

This one works well with copy-mode-vi:

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
# enter copy mode search backward (vi): Alt-s
bind -n M-s copy-mode \; send-keys ?
```